# Swift - key not found error while Json decoding

Tags: json, swift

problem with Json in Swift - trying to decode data, but got error "key not found".
I've check with another key - it works, so maybe it is name wrong?

I'll be grateful for any hint!

Json:

```
{
"created": "2021-10-18T14:55:42.537Z",
"count": 2,
"offset": 0,
"places": [
{
"id": "d1ab65f8-d082-492a-bd70-ce375548dabf",
"type": "Studio",
"type-id": "05fa6a09-ff92-3d34-bdbb-5141d3c24f38",
"score": 100,
"name": "Chipping Norton Recording Studios",
"address": "28–30 New Street, Chipping Norton",
"coordinates": {
"latitude": "51.9414",
"longitude": "-1.548"
},
"area": {6 items},
"life-span": {
"begin": "1971",
"end": "1999-10",
"ended": true
}
},
{8 items}
]
}
```

And my data structure:

```
import Foundation

struct BrainzData: Codable {
    let places: [Places]
}

struct Places: Codable {
    var coordinates: Coordinates
    var lifespan: LifeSpan
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case coordinates
        case lifespan = "life-span"
    }
}

struct Coordinates: Codable {
    let longitude: String
    let latitude: String
}

struct LifeSpan: Codable {
    let begin: String
    var ended: Bool
}
```

Comment: What's the full error message? And could it be that it's one of the places in the JSON which is missing a value, and it's correct in the sample one you gave?

Comment: ... and do you use particular key decoding strategies?

Comment: Im not sure if I get you, but the correct sample was "id". So I get the value. And the struct was built the same way. 

Full error message: 
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "begin", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "places", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 1", intValue: 1), CodingKeys(stringValue: "life-span", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"begin\", intValue: nil) (\"begin\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: The error talks about the **second** item (index 1) in the array `places` which is the first of the invisible `{8 items}`

Comment: How is it possible if I only refer to the first item of array:

            let lat = decodedData.places[0].coordinates.latitude
            let long = decodedData.places[0].coordinates.longitude
            let beg = decodedData.places[0].lifespan.begin
            let end = decodedData.places[0].lifespan.ended

Comment: Latest error:

2021-10-18 20:11:26.977425+0200 MusicBrainz[17606:1570204] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "coordinates", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "places", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 1", intValue: 1)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"coordinates\", intValue: nil) (\"coordinates\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: `JSONDecoder` decodes the entire JSON. `decodedData` contains **all** `places`

Comment: Ok but it doesn't change the fact, that when I only referred to "id" it worked out.
So how adding new keys in my data struct could break down whole request..
So maybe with the data structure is sth wrong.. Don't you think?

Comment: **Read** the JSON. If keys are missing (in array items), declare the corresponding struct members as optional.

Comment: Ok sorry but I'm pre beginner at coding ;) But thank you for help.
Could you tell one thing - how catch all object from json, when don't know exactly how mamy object will be as a search result?

Comment: This depends on the structure of the JSON. If the search results are returned in an array just `count` the items.

Comment: To be clear: Each "items" of your JSON isn't fully the same. Some keys are missing in some cases. So you need to handle these cases of missing keys.

Answer (score 1):

try to decode all data from api and you may see some key - values pairs are null. You may want to change your parameters as optinal. So first change you struct as

```
struct Coordinates: Codable {
    let longitude: String?
    let latitude: String?
}

struct LifeSpan: Codable {
    let begin: String?
    var ended: Bool?
}
```

then log your data such as:

```
guard let responseData = data else { return }
                     do {
                         let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: .mutableContainers)
                         let apiResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(BrainzData.self, from: responseData)
                         print(apiResponse)
                        
                    } catch {
                     print(error)
}
```

data is the same in session.dataTask func

```
task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in })
```

Comment: `mutableContainers` is pointless in Swift especially if you assign the result to an **im**mutable constant.

Comment: then, you may make objects mutable just with the var keyword.

Comment: Yes, the option makes sense only in Objective-C. In Swift it's completely useless. Delete the `options` parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It finally works! :) 
No for example I have 3 different latitude values. How I can get to each of them and use in controller? 
Please could you give yet one tip how to structure the data from JSON? I should make a list?